# What is the expected result for the number of heads obtained in this coin/dice flipping example?

Tags: probability, summation, binomial-distribution, expected-value

Suppose you roll one fair six-sided die and then flip as many coins as the number showing on the die. (For example, if the die shows 4, then you flip four coins.) Let Y be the number of heads obtained. Compute $E(Y)$.

So, $E(Y)=\Sigma_{y=1}^{y=6}yP_{y}(y)$

We will define $X$ as the number on the die. Therefore:

$$E(Y)=\sum_{y=1}^{y=6}yP_{y}(y)=\sum_{y=0}^{y=6}\sum_{x=1}^{x=6}(y)P(X=x,Y=y)=\sum_{y=0}^{y=6}y\sum_{x=1}^{x=6}(1/6)\binom{x}{y}(1/2)^x$$

This inner equation is valid: $(1/6)\binom{x}{y}(1/2)^x$

Basically, it says that if I roll a 3, and I get 1 head only, what is the probability of that occurring = $(1/6)\text{[for the roll]}\binom{3}{1}\text{[from 3 rolls, we choose one head]}(1/2)^3=1/16$

Now, I need to simplify the above double sum, but I am not sure how to do it. The answer in my textbook is $7/4$, but it does not show steps. I think I am right until now, I just need help doing this summation.

Comment: The double sum is finite? You just plug in the numbers? See [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/rhdffk5lto).

Comment: You can also use the "law of total expectation" $E[Y] = \sum_{d=1}^6 E[Y|X=d]P[X=d]$.

Comment: @Michael well it's actually supposed to be $\binom{x}{y}(1/2)^y(1/2)^{x-y}$, but I simplified it

Comment: Oh you are right, I was misinterpreting $x$ (I will delete that comment).  But that is a difficult way to solve the problem.

Comment: What is the simpliest way?

Comment: Without doing any double sums it is obvious that the result is ${7\over4}$: On average you get $3.5$ dots per throw of the die, and half of that for a head afterwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $D$ is the result of the die-throw, $E(Y) = \sum_{d=1}^6 E(Y|D=d)P(D=d)$.

Clearly $E(Y|D=d)= \frac{d}{2}$. So we are left with $$E(Y) = \sum_{d=1}^6 \frac{1}{6}\frac{d}{2} = \frac{1}{12}\sum_{d=1}^6 d = \frac{21}{12}$$

Comment: Sorry, I have not learned this conditional expectation yet, but regardless, how did you get $d/2$? Is it just the probability of a head?

Comment: @KSplitX binomial expectation is nr of trials time chance of success.